# Parsing a date with an +0000 and T

Tags: java, localdate

I am having trouble parsing the following date into a LocalDate object.

**2017-11-10T14:17:38.611+0000**

I tried the following:

`LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(markitDate, DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE)`

but, I get an error that the letter T cannot be parsed.

Comment: Check the [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) first. `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`. It use `Z       zone-offset                 offset-Z          +0000; -0800; -08:00;`

Comment: I get an error saying it index 23 cannot be parsed. index 23 is the + character.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this explicitly, maybe there's a defined pattern out there already but, the following worked:

```
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(markitDate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to sources of DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE:

```
 * The ISO date formatter that formats or parses a date without an
 * offset, such as '20111203'
```

and you trying to parse date and time

Comment: still complains about the T character

Answer (score 0):

Because it is not a `BASIC_ISO_DATE`.

Take a look at [the other predefined formatters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and you will find that `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` is the right choice here. Use it like this:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(markitDate, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)
```

Comment: Complains about the + character now.

Comment: Can you amend your input to 00:00

Comment: The problem is not the ``+`` but the timezone offset. It should be ``00:00`` instead of ``0000``.

Comment: The input is from another system that I cannot change.